# Visual Studio Fails to build when adding a predeployment script;

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure-devops, build

I am getting this error when I try to build.

Se

```
verity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       04094: "C:\Sources\Repos\Dir\PreDeployment\PreDeployment.sql;C:\Sources\Repos\Dir\PreDeployment\PreDeployment.sql" is an invalid value for the "PredeployItem" parameter of the "SqlScriptDependenciesTask" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".   Dir C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets   512
```

All I have added is a pre deployment script.

```
  <SqlScriptDependenciesTask
      PostdeployItem="@(PostDeploy->'%(FullPath)')"
      **PredeployItem="@(PreDeploy->'%(FullPath)')"**
      BuildExtensionConfiguration="@(BuildExtensionConfiguration)"
      DeploymentExtensionConfiguration="@(DeploymentExtensionConfiguration)"
      SqlCmdVariables="@(SqlCmdVariables)">
```

I can't find a solution anywhere?

I have the solution set up as
[image]

The post deployment has been working fine. So I added a Pre Deployment. That doesn't seem to

The sqlproj

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PostDeploy Include="PostDeployment\PostDeployment.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PreDeploy Include="PreDeployment\PreDeployment.sql" />
  </ItemGroup>
```